# Transform text value to lower case when indexing

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Any idea how can I transform text value to lower case when indexing in firestore function. I have tried this

```
const newRef = db.collection("user").where("profile.companyName".toLowerCase(), ">=", data.value.toLowerCase())
```

but it give me an error at this part

```
"profile.companyName".toLowerCase()
```

Is it even possible to do it? I really don't want to save all names to lowercase to be able to properly indexing through my names and then  capitalise them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore doesn't have an API or mechanism to do this for you.  You will have to store the lowercased version of the string in a field, and use that field to make your query.

Comment: @Doug_Stevenson. Thanks for the answer. I was little afraid of that.